# Handling Cyrillic Encoding

Tags: php, html

I have a small problem, I'm using a .php page to show Russian characters. Now, I do this in two different ways. The text I take from the database shows fine, but if I show text like this

`<h2>привет </h2>` it doesn't show it at all. One thing worth mentioning is that I include my navigation file `require_once "navigation.php"` where I declare all the meta data etc.

So from navigation.php:

`<meta charset="Cyrillic(Windows-1251)">`

Solutions I've tried so far:

- Adding encoding to .htaccess
- Using php to output header encoding
- Using Cyrillic(Windows-1251), UTF8, UTF16, iso-8859-5
- Saving the file itself as UTF8

And I'm out of ideas. What I don't understand is how echoing the text from database works, but the HTML version doesn't.

Comment: What is "doesn't show at all"? I mean, do you literally get nothing? If so, that would be a problem with displaying the text at all, not with the encoding.

Comment: Assuming you get mojikbake, can you open the php file in an encoding-aware editor? What does that show the encoding is? And the result in the browser, what does the browser think the encoding is? (For instance, with Firefox's "Get Page Info")

Comment: @MrLister , doesn't show at all means empty space, no characters whatsoever. Firefox thinks UTF8 is the encoding, which should be able to display russian characters? I'm not sure what do you mean by "problem with displaying the text" the paragraph shows english if it's mixed, but doesn't show russian at all. The russian characters were copy pasted from a skype convo, but I did try to simply type them in (so they hold no metadata) and it still fails. Sublime says UTF8

Comment: I mean if the problem would only be an encoding mismatch, then the browser would show _something_. The above text, displayed by a program that thinks it's windows-1252, would come out as `Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚`, not blanks. (Even if the browser couldn't display Cyrillic at all, it should show at least show squares or question marks.) So, something else is going on. Maybe you're spot on with the metadata remark. What happens if you insert some ASCII chars in the middle of the Cyrillic text? Type some Cyrillic yourself, or copy Cyrillic characters from a trusted source, CharMap or something.

Comment: Or it could be something as silly as the h2 element hidden by CSS.

Comment: Hah I check css, it's all good. If I give the page this:
`<h2>приproblemsвет</h2>` it displays "problems" only. This is trully an amazing issue. I tried typing cyrillic in Russian/Serbian from both Windows 7, Winodws 8, copied from other HTML pages in Russian and copied from CharMap and Skype. 

However, the "problems" displayed doesn't act like text o_o I can't select it with my cursor like I should be able too

Comment: @MrLister I just found something interesting. 
My database link has this:
`mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);` if I set encoding to: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; UTF-8">` the site (both php echoed and html coded) shows `Ð›Ñ„Ð¸Ñ‰ÐºÑƒÑ‚Ñ„ ÑƒÑ‹ÐµÑ„ Ñ„Ñ€Ñ‰ÐºÑ„` but if I change encoding to: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` php echo works fine, html chars don't show at all. I'm stunned

Comment: I'm out of ideas now. Are you saying that `<?php echo "<h2>привет</h2>"; ?>` works as expected, but `<h2>привет</h2>` by itself shows nothing? I don't know what to suggest then. Except, echo everything. By the way, the `"text/html; UTF-8"` in your comment is an incorrect content type, so it will be ignored by the browser.

Comment: @MrLister no but rather, `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $title = $row['Title']; } echo $title;` that works (there's a query before). I've moved the entire setup (including files, messing with encodings) to a different host and it works. I'm going to poke hosting check what's wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was somewhere in the JS. For this project, I was given complete HTML works, just to hook PHP to it. The HTML, among other things, had this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
```

I have no idea what it does except it makes fonts smaller (why use JS for that is beyond me). So simple removal of that left me with a bit bigger font size, but working Cyrillic characters.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this should work

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-5">
<h2>привет </h2>
```

Comment: When I test that, it displays `аПбаИаВаЕб`.